# Deformations of quotient singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, singularity-theory

Let $Y$ be an affine scheme over a field of characteristic zero. Suppose we have a group $G$ acting on $Y$ and that the subset of $Y$ of points with non-trivial stabilizer is in codimension greater or equal than $3$. Then, by a theorem due to Schlessinger $X:=Y/G$ is rigid that is $X$ does not have non-trivial first order deformations.

I know that a quadric cone in $\mathbb{A}^{3}$ admits non-trivial first order deformations.

**Does anyone know an example of a $3$-fold with finite quotient singularities and singular in codimension $2$ admitting non-trivial first order deformations?**

**Is it true the naive statement: "the dimension of the space of deformations is bigger for a bad singularity than for a mild one"?**

**For instance is it true that non-canonical singularities are not rigid?**

Thank you very much.

Comment: For your first question,a stupid example is $\mathbb{A}^1\times Q$, where $Q$ is a quadric cone in $\mathbb{A}^3$.

Comment: I think that is a non-stupid example. A codimension two finite quotient singularity in dimension $3$ has to locally look like $\mathbb A^1 \times X$ for $X$ a finite quotient singularity in dimension $2$.

Comment: @WillSawin:  "A codimension two finite quotient singularity ... has to locally look like ..."  I believe this is incorrect.  For instance, let the Klein Viergruppe, $V=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3/\Delta(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ act on $\mathbb{A}^3$ by $\overline{e}_1(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (x_1,-x_2,-x_3)$, and similarly for $\overline{e}_2$ and $\overline{e}_3$.  The quotient is the hypersurface in $\mathbb{A}^4$ of points $(y_1,y_2,y_3,z)$ such that $y_1y_2y_3-z^2 = 0$, where $y_i = x_i^2$ and $z = x_1x_2x_3$.  This germ is not smooth over a two-dimensional germ.

Comment: I should have said that locally somewhere it looks like that, not locally everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your last question, the answer is **yes**, since there are terminal singularities that are *not* rigid.

For instance, in the recent preprint by Taro Sano *[On deformations of Fano threefolds with terminal singularities](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.6323)* it is shown that any $\mathbb{Q}$-Fano threefold with "ordinary" terminal singularities (the meaning of "ordinary" is explained in the paper) can be deformed to a $\mathbb{Q}$-Fano threefold with only quotient singularities.

Moreover, the Kuranishi space of a $\mathbb{Q}$-Fano 3-fold $X$ is smooth, hence all first-order deformations of $X$ are unobstructed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I look at the paper. You are right there are non-rigid terminal singularities. Do you think the following is true: "Let $X$ be a normal variety with finite quotient canonical singularities in codimension two. Then $X$ is not rigid". Thank you.